# Reorder / arrange bars in a plot(table) while keeping value names

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the result of `table` in a decreasing order, but if I sort the table before plotting it the plot does not show the value names anymore.

`a <- data.frame(var = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"))`

`plot(table(a))`

[image: plot_table]

`plot(sort(table(a)))`

[image: plot_sort_table]

Comment: You can just use barplot(sort(table(a))) and the names are back, depending what you want to do modify your input to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the count with `table` ('tbl'), `order` the elements and assign it to 'tbl' to keep the same structure as in 'tbl' and then `plot`.  In the OP's code, the `sort` or `order` converts the `table` class to `matrix`.

```
tbl <- table(a)
tbl[] <- tbl[order(tbl)]
plot(tbl)
```

[image]